# Что бы список раскрывался вверх (select, option)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите, как сделать чтобы раскрывающийся список раскрывался вверх?

```
<select id="pick-filter">
  <option value="">All cuisines</option>
  <option value="1">Arabian</option>
  <option value="2">Asian</option>
  <option value="3">Bagels</option>
</select>
```

Comment: нативный селект сам выбирает в какую сторону открываться, и открывается вверх, если выпадающий список находится слишком близко к низу экрана и при открытии не вместится в него.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Со стандартным `<select>` сделать этот никак нельзя. Стандартный `<select>` кастомизируется очень плохо. Несколько первых запросов гугла дают это ясно понять: [тут](http://www.sql.ru/forum/393237/html-mozhno-li-zadat-napravlenie-elementa-select) и [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/248243/). Особенно это касается оформления `<option>`.

Если вы хотите сделать красивейший `<select>`, а тем более с раскрытием вверх, то вам придётся писать свой `select`. Например, я использую блоки `<div>` и `<input type="hidden">` + `js` в своих селектах. На хабре есть статья (ссылка выше), где автор использует `<label> + <div> + <input>`.

Пример моего селекта с раскрытием вверх (может кто напишет лучше, а мой код, по его мнению, плохой, тогда милости прошу написать свой ответ):

Содержимое HTML:

```
<div class="select">
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="1">
    <div class="selected">Arabian</div>
    <div class="option-list">
        <div class="option" data-select-val="0">All cuisines</div>
        <div class="option" data-select-val="1">Arabian</div>
        <div class="option" data-select-val="2">Asian</div>
        <div class="option" data-select-val="3">Bagels</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

А вот JS-код:

```
$(function(){
    $('.selected').click(function(){
        $('.option-list').slideToggle(200);
        $('.select').toggleClass('select-active');
    });
    $('.option').click(function(){
        select_val = $(this).attr('data-select-val');
        select_div = $(this).parent().parent();
        $(select_div).children('.selected').html($(this).html());
        $(select_div).children('input').val(select_val);

        $('.option-list').slideToggle(200);
        $('.select').toggleClass('select-active');
    });
});
```

CSS-код не менее важен:

```
.select{
    position: relative;

    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.selected{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option-list{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: -1px;

    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
}
.option{
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option:hover{
    background: #fff;
}
```

Я сделал готовый [пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/intro94/www00khx/).

По умолчанию `input` и `.selected` содержат ваше дефолтное значение селекта. Я использую `$('.selected').html()`, а не `$('.selected').text();`, потому что оптионы могут для красоты содержать картинки и тд (например у меня именно так и есть - выбор языков с иконкой языка:

```
<div class="option" data-select-val="ru">
    <div class="ico-lng ico-lng-ru"></div>Русский
</div>
```

Вроде всё. Если что - спрашивайте.

Comment: @LADYX всегда рад помочь. ;)